# Instagram server side authentication 2019

Tags: node.js, authentication, instagram-api

I just can't get it right.

There are [docs](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/) for instagram api that says do one call, it will redirect user to a page where he authenticate, then you get code from Redirect Url and now using this code you can get token. That is working and it is just fine. But, what if i want to do a website for myself as personal page and show my own instagram photos filtered by tag to ANYONE. I don't need OAuth, any login. I'm ok with creating Node server and make a call smth like this:

```
http://api.instagram.com/auth?client_id_or_login=vvinog&password=secretpassword
```

and get token from this call. But it looks like in the internet no one do this, or i dump?
Can you please advice some tutorial, approach that allows me to do that?
Any code snippets are super welcome.

Comment: I am facing the same problem but can't find the solution anywhere :(